# Iterate through child objects of an object without the usage of `foreach`

Tags: php, oop, web, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterating through stdClass obj’s that are contained within a parent stdClass Obj. (aka: iterating through child objects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161209/iterating-through-stdclass-objs-that-are-contained-within-a-parent-stdclass-obj)

...bccause if the parent object is empty `foreach` shows an error. `for()` would be my preferred loop logic but I do not know how to access the child objects properties.

Work-ish code:

```
foreach ($main_object as $object) {
    $object->value = $object->value * 3.14;
}
```

**BUT** when `$main_object` is empty or null, `foreach` dumps out an error.

I'm looking for something more like this:

(pseudo) code:

```
for ($p = 0; $p < counter($main_object); $p++) {
    //$p being the index'd id of the child object. That is where I'm having issues, how do I refer to child X within a parent object.
    $main_object->$p->value = $main_object->$p->value * 3.14;
}
```

Now if '$main_object' is empty/null no error is thrown, logic keeps on truckin'.

How do I access child object `$x->properties` when object is one of a group of child objects inside a parent object?

Comment: @devOp You don't need to see the class to answer this question, I'm sure op wants it to apply for *any* object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check first that the object contains at least one item before iterating:

```
if($a && count($a)){
    // iterate using foreach
}
```

I too find this annoying, but `foreach` is extremely easy to work with so it's a bit of a tradeoff.  I'd still rather do the above than use something like `for` (which could also work).

[PHP count docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Cheers

Comment: Erg... what I wanted to avoid. Typically I do:

if (!empty($main_object)) {
foreach ($main_object as $object) {
...
}}

and it works great, as you pointed out. Really would think foreach would say "O look, 'A' has nothing in it Im done" instead of throwing an error.

You get credit for the answer as you understand how annoying it is (and kept it OOP).

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `get_class_vars` which returns all attributes of your class in an array. And then iterate through with for-loop. And you can access them with the array key and the object:

```
$aryAttr = get_class_vars($main_object);
for ($p = 0; $p < count($aryAttr); $p++) {
    $key=key($aryAttr);
    $main_object->$key>value = $main_object->$key->value *3.14;
    next($aryAttr);
}
```

This might help, but didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you check if main_object is empty or not before you do the foreach loop

```
if($main_object->child != null)
{
  foreach ($main_object->child as $object)
 {
    $object->value = $object->value * 3.14;
 }
}
```

Comment: Will still result in an error if `$main_object` has no publicly visible members to iterate over.

Comment: my bad ,you are right there should be a property(i'e a collection) that holds the child object(s)